# How to diff multiline strings with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am generating some XML using a builder, and would like to compare the results to some file contents.  However, since the strings are so long, the output is hard to read when the strings differ.

I know there are a number of libraries for diffing strings in ruby, but is there a built in facility in rspec for generating multiline string comparison failures that are easier to read?

Comment: Updating the question:  I just found the --diff option in the spec command line, but it doesn't appear to work - output is the same when I expect two strings to be eql and they aren't whether I use --diff or not.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, got it.  You need to use the --diff option with the following:

```
actual_multiline_string.should == expected_multiline_string
```

NOT

```
actual_multiline_string.should eql(expected_multiline_string)
```